# zurb foundation bind magellan arrive

Tags: jquery, zurb-foundation

I need to bind an event once the arrival is reached.

The documentation ( http://foundation.zurb.com/docs/v/3.2.5/magellan.php) states that you can access the magellan.arrival event, but gives no examples on how to use it.

I have tried this but it's mot working:

```
$('dd[data-magellan-arrival]').on('arrival',function(){
  console.log('arrived');
})

$('dd[data-magellan-arrival]').on('magellan.arrival',function(){
  console.log('arrived');
})
```

I have also googled and checked the latest documentation but can find nothing at all related to this event.

Comment: Do you have a JsFiddle or CodePen?  BTW... Zurb is up to version 5.5.x

Comment: Are you using version 3.2.5 or the latest version?